# How to solve Flutter error while trying to write in a file: "OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1"?

Tags: android, flutter, file-writing, oserror

I am trying to write in a .txt file in my flutter program. I am using Permission_handler package and when I run the code (using **mi 10**) the app ask for permission to access to media and file and I hit allow, and the Debug console says **"I/flutter (15890): PermissionStatus.granted"** (I mean i did all the part about updating the AndroidManifest.xml or modification on "gradle.properties" , etc.). But when it comes to writing in the file, it throws this error:

```
E/flutter (15890): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/X.txt' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

I really appreciate any thought on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Mi 10** runs on Android 10. You need to add the following attribute to the `<application>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

This opts you into the legacy storage model.

Also set `targetSdkVersion` to 29, and `compileSdkVersion` to 29 or 30 in `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks @Joy for your answer. But it still shows the same error.
E/flutter (31011): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/X.txt' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Comment: my Mi 10 android version is not 10, it is 11. Do you have any suggestion on it?

Comment: Try to set `targetSdkVersion` to 29 and `compileSdkVersion` to 30 in `build.gradle`.

Comment: @afsane did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happening in Android 11 due to their new changes. So you have to add one more permission (`manageExternalStorage`).

Like this

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {

  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.manageExternalStorage
  ].request();//Permission.manageExternalStorage
}
```

Even you have to add read & write permission as well.

Comment: I am not working on that project anymore, so I cannot try this. But anyway thank you for tacking time.